# Theming pycharm with pywal using Intellij Material Theme and Scheme Generator

Tags: python, pycharm, manjaro

I want to theme PyCharm using a pywal generated color palette. I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/0x6C38/intellijPywal):
and theming works for konsole (KDE's default terminal emulator), spicetify (cli application to theme spotify), etc. (so pywal works).
I use manjaro KDE. Did anyone have a problem setting this up or did I miss something?
The UI theme seems to work (accent color is a little off) but the editor scheme is a mess...